# Load XML null values and incorrect import

Tags: mysql, xml

I am having trouble importing a XML document into my MySQL database. Using Load XML Local imports null values and incorrect values. I've researched at length what could be the cause of this, but I cannot find anything related. This is all being done on our local development environment, using WAMPServer 3.1.0.

I start with creating my import table. I initialise it using the datatypes specified by the XML file provider, with our own localID as the primary key. As the XML file has encoding="iso-8859-1", I set the character set as latin1. The errors also occurs when the table is initialised using utf8.

```
CREATE TABLE propertyImport (
    localID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    propertyID BIGINT(20), 
    branchID TINYINT(3), 
    clientName VARCHAR(100), 
    branchName VARCHAR(50), 
    department ENUM('Sales','Lettings','Commercial','Agricultural'), 
    referenceNumber VARCHAR(20), 
    addressName VARCHAR(50), 
    addressNumber VARCHAR(50), 
    addressStreet VARCHAR(50), 
    address2 VARCHAR(50), 
    address3 VARCHAR(50), 
    address4 VARCHAR(50), 
    addressPostcode VARCHAR(15), 
    country VARCHAR(40), 
    displayAddress VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature1 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature2 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature3 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature4 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature5 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature6 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature7 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature8 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature9 VARCHAR(100), 
    propertyFeature10 VARCHAR(100), 
    dateLastModified DATE, 
    timeLastModified TIME, 
    featuredProperty TINYINT(1), 
    regionID INT(11), 
    latitude DECIMAL(9,7), 
    longitude DECIMAL(9,7), 
    mainSummary LONGTEXT, 
    fullDescription LONGTEXT, 
    propertyBedrooms TINYINT(2), 
    propertyBathrooms TINYINT(2), 
    propertyEnsuites TINYINT(2), 
    propertyReceptionRooms TINYINT(2), 
    propertyKitchens TINYINT(2), 
    propertyAge TINYINT(4),
    floorArea DECIMAL(6,2), 
    floorAreaUnits VARCHAR(8), 
    displayPropertyType VARCHAR(50), 
    propertyType TINYINT(4), 
    propertyStyle TINYINT(4), 
    availability TINYINT(2),
    price INT(11), 
    forSalePOA TINYINT(1), 
    priceQualifier SMALLINT(4), 
    propertyTenure SMALLINT(4), 
    saleBy SMALLINT(4), 
    developmentOpportunity TINYINT(1), 
    investmentOpportunity TINYINT(1), 
    estimatedRentalIncome DECIMAL(7,2), 
    rent DECIMAL(7,2), 
    rentFrequency SMALLINT(4), 
    toLetPOA TINYINT(1), 
    studentProperty TINYINT(1), 
    lettingFeePolicyHeadline VARCHAR(50), 
    lettingFeePolicyDetails TEXT, 
    forSale TINYINT(1),
    toLet TINYINT(1),
    priceTo INT(11),
    priceFrom INT(11),
    rentTo DECIMAL(7,2),
    rentFrom DECIMAL(7,2),
    floorAreaTo DECIMAL(6,2),
    floorAreaFrom DECIMAL(6,2),
    siteArea DECIMAL(7,2),
    siteAreaUnits VARCHAR(8),
    strapLine VARCHAR(255),
    landAreaTo DECIMAL(7,2),
    landAreaFrom DECIMAL(7,2),
    landAreaUnits VARCHAR(8),
    forSaleLeaseLength SMALLINT(4),
    featured TINYINT(1), 
    available TINYINT(1)
) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

Next I import the XML using the Load XML Local. In this example, I identify the rows using 'propertyID'.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/wamp64/tmp/output.xml' INTO TABLE propertyimport ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<propertyID>';
```

This is a shortened example of the XML file I am importing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>
    <properties>
        <property>
            <propertyID>101466000123</propertyID>
            <branchID>1</branchID>
            <clientName>Unihousing</clientName>
            <branchName>Birmingham</branchName>
            <department>Lettings</department>
            <referenceNumber>174</referenceNumber>
            <addressName>Downstairs Front Apartment</addressName>
            <addressNumber>174</addressNumber>
            <addressStreet>Dawlish Road</addressStreet>
            <address2></address2>
            <address3>Birmingham</address3>
            <address4></address4>
            <addressPostcode>B29 7AR</addressPostcode>
            <country>United Kingdom</country>
            <displayAddress>Dawlish Road</displayAddress>

            <propertyBedrooms>0</propertyBedrooms>
            <propertyBathrooms>1</propertyBathrooms>
            <propertyEnsuites>0</propertyEnsuites>
            <propertyReceptionRooms>0</propertyReceptionRooms>
            <propertyKitchens>0</propertyKitchens>
            <displayPropertyType>Studio</displayPropertyType>
            <propertyType>2</propertyType>
            <propertyStyle>20</propertyStyle>
            <propertyAge>0</propertyAge>
            <floorArea>0.00</floorArea>
            <floorAreaUnits>sq ft</floorAreaUnits>
            <propertyFeature1>Fitted Kitchen With Combi Oven </propertyFeature1>
            <propertyFeature2>Fitted Shower Room</propertyFeature2>
            <propertyFeature3>Shared Utility Area</propertyFeature3>
            <propertyFeature4>Next to the University of Birmingham</propertyFeature4>
            <propertyFeature5>Close to Selly Oak Village</propertyFeature5>
            <propertyFeature6>HMO studio style living </propertyFeature6>
            <propertyFeature7></propertyFeature7>
            <propertyFeature8></propertyFeature8>
            <propertyFeature9></propertyFeature9>
            <propertyFeature10></propertyFeature10>
                <rent>140</rent>
                <rentFrequency>2</rentFrequency>
            <toLetPOA>0</toLetPOA>
                <studentProperty>1</studentProperty>
            <availability>2</availability>
            <mainSummary> A brand new HMO style property consisting of: A brand new modern fitted snack area, an open plan living/ dining area and a fitted shower room. This spacious accommodation on offer is fully double glazed and fully furnished with student essentials. The cleaning and upkeep of the communal stairs and landing are carried out by us. It is located next to the university and the busy night life of Selly Oak Village is just a short walk away. You wouldn't want to miss out so call now to arrange your viewing!!!</mainSummary>
            <fullDescription><![CDATA[]]></fullDescription>
            <dateLastModified>2018-05-23</dateLastModified>
            <timeLastModified>14:07:32</timeLastModified>
            <featuredProperty>0</featuredProperty>
            <regionID>56</regionID>
            <latitude>52.4408</latitude>
            <longitude>-1.92888</longitude>
            <flags>
            </flags>
            <images>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_17_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_11_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_8_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_14_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_15_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_18_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_19_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_20_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_21_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2018-02-15 10:34:07">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/123/IMG_123_22_large.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <floorplans>
            </floorplans>
            <epcGraphs>
            </epcGraphs>
            <epcFrontPages><epcFrontPage modified="2015-06-09 09:53:42">http://epc.jupix.co.uk/647u85t</epcFrontPage>
            </epcFrontPages>
            <brochures>
            </brochures>
            <virtualTours>
            </virtualTours>
            <externalLinks>
            </externalLinks>
        </property>
        <property>
            <propertyID>101466000124</propertyID>
            <branchID>1</branchID>
            <clientName>Unihousing</clientName>
            <branchName>Birmingham</branchName>
            <department>Lettings</department>
            <referenceNumber>174</referenceNumber>
            <addressName>Middle Front Apartment</addressName>
            <addressNumber>174</addressNumber>
            <addressStreet>Dawlish Road</addressStreet>
            <address2></address2>
            <address3>Selly Oak </address3>
            <address4></address4>
            <addressPostcode>B29 7AR</addressPostcode>
            <country>United Kingdom</country>
            <displayAddress>Dawlish Road</displayAddress>

            <propertyBedrooms>0</propertyBedrooms>
            <propertyBathrooms>1</propertyBathrooms>
            <propertyEnsuites>0</propertyEnsuites>
            <propertyReceptionRooms>0</propertyReceptionRooms>
            <propertyKitchens>0</propertyKitchens>
            <displayPropertyType>Studio</displayPropertyType>
            <propertyType>2</propertyType>
            <propertyStyle>20</propertyStyle>
            <propertyAge>0</propertyAge>
            <floorArea>0.00</floorArea>
            <floorAreaUnits>sq ft</floorAreaUnits>
            <propertyFeature1>Next to the University of Birmingham</propertyFeature1>
            <propertyFeature2>Electric Heating</propertyFeature2>
            <propertyFeature3>Combi Oven </propertyFeature3>
            <propertyFeature4>Shared Utility Areas</propertyFeature4>
            <propertyFeature5>HMO studio style living</propertyFeature5>
            <propertyFeature6></propertyFeature6>
            <propertyFeature7></propertyFeature7>
            <propertyFeature8></propertyFeature8>
            <propertyFeature9></propertyFeature9>
            <propertyFeature10></propertyFeature10>
                <rent>140</rent>
                <rentFrequency>2</rentFrequency>
            <toLetPOA>1</toLetPOA>
                <studentProperty>1</studentProperty>
            <availability>2</availability>
            <mainSummary>AVAILABLE JULY 2018 newly refurbished HMO studio style. Features a fitted snack area, a bedroom/living area &amp;amp; fitted shower room. Shared utility area. Refurbished to a high standard, inclusive of bills and internet, TV also supplied at no extra cost. The property is laminated throughout and benefits from central heating and double glazing. The cleaning and upkeep of the communal stairs and landing are carried out by us. The property is in prime location within a short walking distance from the University of Birmingham &amp;amp; Selly Oak train station.</mainSummary>
            <fullDescription><![CDATA[<strong></strong> <strong></strong> Newly refurbished student accommodation. This Open plan 1 bed flat in Selly Oak, features a fitted kitchen with combi-oven, a bedroom/living area &#38; fitted shower room. Shared utility area. A must see property. This apartment is suitable for a couple sharing. We have 6 more studio apartments available in the same block. Selly Oak, is an ideal location for any student within a few minutes' walk there are supermarkets, shops, bars and restaurants.  ]]></fullDescription>
            <dateLastModified>2018-05-23</dateLastModified>
            <timeLastModified>12:42:16</timeLastModified>
            <featuredProperty>0</featuredProperty>
            <regionID>56</regionID>
            <latitude>52.4404</latitude>
            <longitude>-1.92931</longitude>
            <flags>
            <flag>Price Reduction</flag>
            </flags>
            <images>
                <image modified="2017-11-09 12:16:39">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_9_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-09 12:16:39">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_7_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-09 12:16:39">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_5_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-09 12:16:39">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_6_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-09 12:16:39">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_8_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-25 13:22:12">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_10_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-25 13:22:13">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_11_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-25 13:22:13">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_12_large.jpg</image>
                <image modified="2017-11-25 13:22:13">http://media2.jupix.co.uk/v3/clients/1466/properties/124/IMG_124_13_large.jpg</image>
            </images>
            <floorplans>
            </floorplans>
            <epcGraphs>
            </epcGraphs>
            <epcFrontPages><epcFrontPage modified="2015-06-09 10:06:56">http://epc.jupix.co.uk/65rsea0</epcFrontPage>
            </epcFrontPages>
            <brochures>
            </brochures>
            <virtualTours>
            </virtualTours>
            <externalLinks>
            </externalLinks>
        </property>
    </properties>
```

The import succeeds without any warnings. When I query the table to select all records, I get the output below. Clearly the first property has not imported at all, however, the second property actually has the wrong data as well, it has the missing data from the first property, despite it having the correct propertyID.

```
| localID | propertyID   | branchID | clientName | branchName | department | referenceNumber | addressName                | addressNumber | addressStreet | address2 | address3   | address4 | addressPostcode | country        | displayAddress | propertyFeature1                | propertyFeature2   | propertyFeature3    | propertyFeature4                     | propertyFeature5           | propertyFeature6         | propertyFeature7 | propertyFeature8 | propertyFeature9 | propertyFeature10 | dateLastModified | timeLastModified | featuredProperty | regionID | latitude | longitude | mainSummary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | fullDescription | propertyBedrooms | propertyBathrooms | propertyEnsuites | propertyReceptionRooms | propertyKitchens | propertyAge | floorArea | floorAreaUnits | displayPropertyType | propertyType | propertyStyle | availability | price | forSalePOA | priceQualifier | propertyTenure | saleBy | developmentOpportunity | investmentOpportunity | estimatedRentalIncome | rent   | rentFrequency | toLetPOA | studentProperty | lettingFeePolicyHeadline | lettingFeePolicyDetails | forSale | toLet | priceTo | priceFrom | rentTo | rentFrom | floorAreaTo | floorAreaFrom | siteArea | siteAreaUnits | strapLine | landAreaTo | landAreaFrom | landAreaUnits | forSaleLeaseLength | featured | available |
+---------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------+----------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------+------------+----------------+----------------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+
|       1 | 101466000123 |     NULL | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       | NULL            | NULL                       | NULL          | NULL          | NULL     | NULL       | NULL     | NULL            | NULL           | NULL           | NULL                            | NULL               | NULL                | NULL                                 | NULL                       | NULL                     | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             |             NULL |     NULL |     NULL |      NULL | NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NULL            |             NULL |              NULL |             NULL |                   NULL |             NULL |        NULL |      NULL | NULL           | NULL                |         NULL |          NULL |         NULL |  NULL |       NULL |           NULL |           NULL |   NULL |                   NULL |                  NULL |                  NULL |   NULL |          NULL |     NULL |            NULL | NULL                     | NULL                    |    NULL |  NULL |    NULL |      NULL |   NULL |     NULL |        NULL |          NULL |     NULL | NULL          | NULL      |       NULL |         NULL | NULL          |               NULL |     NULL |      NULL |
|       2 | 101466000124 |        1 | Unihousing | Birmingham | Lettings   | 174             | Downstairs Front Apartment | 174           | Dawlish Road  | NULL     | Birmingham | NULL     | B29 7AR         | United Kingdom | Dawlish Road   | Fitted Kitchen With Combi Oven  | Fitted Shower Room | Shared Utility Area | Next to the University of Birmingham | Close to Selly Oak Village | HMO studio style living  | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | NULL             | NULL             |             NULL |     NULL |     NULL |      NULL | A brand new HMO style property consisting of: A brand new modern fitted snack area, an open plan living/ dining area and a fitted shower room. This spacious accommodation on offer is fully double glazed and fully furnished with student essentials. The cleaning and upkeep of the communal stairs and landing are carried out by us. It is located next to the university and the busy night life of Selly Oak Village is just a short walk away. You wouldn't want to miss out so call now to arrange your viewing!!! | NULL            |                0 |                 1 |                0 |                      0 |                0 |           0 |      0.00 | sq ft          | Studio              |            2 |            20 |            2 |  NULL |       NULL |           NULL |           NULL |   NULL |                   NULL |                  NULL |                  NULL | 140.00 |             2 |        0 |               1 | NULL                     | NULL                    |    NULL |  NULL |    NULL |      NULL |   NULL |     NULL |        NULL |          NULL |     NULL | NULL          | NULL      |       NULL |         NULL | NULL          |               NULL |     NULL |      NULL |
```

In the next example, I delete everything from the table and import it again, this time identifying the rows by 'property'.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/wamp64/tmp/output.xml' INTO TABLE propertyimport ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<property>';
```

Again, no warnings or errors. Querying the database for all entries returns the below output. Here, we can see it has imported more, but is still not correct. Row 4 is just a direct copy of row 3, including the propertyID.

```
| localID | propertyID   | branchID | clientName | branchName | department | referenceNumber | addressName                | addressNumber | addressStreet | address2 | address3   | address4 | addressPostcode | country        | displayAddress | propertyFeature1                | propertyFeature2   | propertyFeature3    | propertyFeature4                     | propertyFeature5           | propertyFeature6         | propertyFeature7 | propertyFeature8 | propertyFeature9 | propertyFeature10 | dateLastModified | timeLastModified | featuredProperty | regionID | latitude   | longitude  | mainSummary                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | fullDescription | propertyBedrooms | propertyBathrooms | propertyEnsuites | propertyReceptionRooms | propertyKitchens | propertyAge | floorArea | floorAreaUnits | displayPropertyType | propertyType | propertyStyle | availability | price | forSalePOA | priceQualifier | propertyTenure | saleBy | developmentOpportunity | investmentOpportunity | estimatedRentalIncome | rent   | rentFrequency | toLetPOA | studentProperty | lettingFeePolicyHeadline | lettingFeePolicyDetails | forSale | toLet | priceTo | priceFrom | rentTo | rentFrom | floorAreaTo | floorAreaFrom | siteArea | siteAreaUnits | strapLine | landAreaTo | landAreaFrom | landAreaUnits | forSaleLeaseLength | featured | available |
+---------+--------------+----------+------------+------------+------------+-----------------+----------------------------+---------------+---------------+----------+------------+----------+-----------------+----------------+----------------+---------------------------------+--------------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------------+------------------+-------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+-------+------------+----------------+----------------+--------+------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------+----------+-----------------+--------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+---------------+--------------------+----------+-----------+
|       3 | 101466000123 |        1 | Unihousing | Birmingham | Lettings   | 174             | Downstairs Front Apartment | 174           | Dawlish Road  | NULL     | Birmingham | NULL     | B29 7AR         | United Kingdom | Dawlish Road   | Fitted Kitchen With Combi Oven  | Fitted Shower Room | Shared Utility Area | Next to the University of Birmingham | Close to Selly Oak Village | HMO studio style living  | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | 2018-05-23       | 14:07:32         |                0 |       56 | 52.4408000 | -1.9288800 | A brand new HMO style property consisting of: A brand new modern fitted snack area, an open plan living/ dining area and a fitted shower room. This spacious accommodation on offer is fully double glazed and fully furnished with student essentials. The cleaning and upkeep of the communal stairs and landing are carried out by us. It is located next to the university and the busy night life of Selly Oak Village is just a short walk away. You wouldn't want to miss out so call now to arrange your viewing!!! | NULL            |                0 |                 1 |                0 |                      0 |                0 |           0 |      0.00 | sq ft          | Studio              |            2 |            20 |            2 |  NULL |       NULL |           NULL |           NULL |   NULL |                   NULL |                  NULL |                  NULL | 140.00 |             2 |        0 |               1 | NULL                     | NULL                    |    NULL |  NULL |    NULL |      NULL |   NULL |     NULL |        NULL |          NULL |     NULL | NULL          | NULL      |       NULL |         NULL | NULL          |               NULL |     NULL |      NULL |
|       4 | 101466000123 |        1 | Unihousing | Birmingham | Lettings   | 174             | Downstairs Front Apartment | 174           | Dawlish Road  | NULL     | Birmingham | NULL     | B29 7AR         | United Kingdom | Dawlish Road   | Fitted Kitchen With Combi Oven  | Fitted Shower Room | Shared Utility Area | Next to the University of Birmingham | Close to Selly Oak Village | HMO studio style living  | NULL             | NULL             | NULL             | NULL              | 2018-05-23       | 12:42:16         |                0 |       56 | 52.4404000 | -1.9293100 | A brand new HMO style property consisting of: A brand new modern fitted snack area, an open plan living/ dining area and a fitted shower room. This spacious accommodation on offer is fully double glazed and fully furnished with student essentials. The cleaning and upkeep of the communal stairs and landing are carried out by us. It is located next to the university and the busy night life of Selly Oak Village is just a short walk away. You wouldn't want to miss out so call now to arrange your viewing!!! | NULL            |                0 |                 1 |                0 |                      0 |                0 |           0 |      0.00 | sq ft          | Studio              |            2 |            20 |            2 |  NULL |       NULL |           NULL |           NULL |   NULL |                   NULL |                  NULL |                  NULL | 140.00 |             2 |        0 |               1 | NULL                     | NULL                    |    NULL |  NULL |    NULL |      NULL |   NULL |     NULL |        NULL |          NULL |     NULL | NULL          | NULL      |       NULL |         NULL | NULL          |               NULL |     NULL |      NULL |
```

I have used online tools to check the validity of the XML document, but they have not found any errors. As mentioned above, I've used both latin1 and utf8 character sets but it has not made any difference. I've dropped and remade the table, including doing the import again numerous times. What could be causing this behaviour, and how can I either fix it, or get around it?

Comment: Is it possible that you forgot `IGNORE INTO TABLE propertyImport `?

Comment: @csteusloff I presume you mean to avoid duplicates? If you look at the XML file, the 2 'property' rows are not duplicate. This is not a problem with importing an XML file containing duplicate entries, this is a problem of 2 different entries being imported incorrectly.

Comment: First of all remove 1st part of your question. Correct syntax for your xml file is `IDENTIFIED BY '<property>';` so do not confuse yourself and us. 2nd - there should be some error. Try to add 3rd element to file and then try to reorder elements few times. Lets check the hypothese: is it the element that is the 1st place in file - that duplicates? does it duplicates N times? where N is number of elements in xml?

Comment: Another attempt: try to remove complex nodes `<images>` for exmple.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your reply, and telling me the correct syntax to use. I did as you said and tested removing the complex nodes, however that made no difference. I then added another element, then moved them around to see what the error followed. Turns out the error was following the second element of the XML file. I looked to see what was different between them, and found that the second element had data in the CDATA tag of the node 'fullDescription'. I removed the data inside the CDATA tag and imported again, this time without any problems.